# Check form for URLs before sending (server side)

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

I have the following code which checks the form before submitting on the server side, what I would like to include (if possible) is to check the message for URLs and if present to prevent the message from being sent.

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['fromemail']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && $go == TRUE)
{
    //data has been filled
    $name = Filter::no_html($_POST['name']);
    $from = Filter::no_html($_POST['fromemail']);
    $start_dt = Filter::no_html($_POST['start_dt']);
    $end_dt = Filter::no_html($_POST['end_dt']);
    $comments = Filter::no_html($_POST['message']);
    $validate->isEmpty($name, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_YOUR_NAME);
    $validate->isEmpty($from, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_YOUR_EMAIL);
    $validate->isSingleEmail($from, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER_EMAIL);
    $validate->isEmpty($start_dt, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_START_DATE);
    $validate->isEmpty($end_dt, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_END_DATE);
    $validate->isEmpty($comments, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_YOUR_MESSAGE);
    $modules->call_hook('contact_owner_submit', ''); // Call any module functions
    $id = (int) @$_POST['ownerid'];
    $vehicle = (int) @$_POST['listingid'];

    if ($validate->isError())
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

You could search the message using the stristr method for certain criteria within the string:

```
$has_url = (stristr($comments, 'http') || stristr($comments, 'www.'));
if($has_url) {
  // prevent submit
}
```

More info on the stristr method here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

So your code could look like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['fromemail']) && !empty($_POST['message']) && $go == TRUE) {

  $has_url = (stristr($_POST['message'], 'http') || stristr($_POST['message'], 'www.'));
  if($has_url) {
    // whatever happens if contains url
  }

  $name = Filter::no_html($_POST['name']);
  $from = Filter::no_html($_POST['fromemail']);
  $start_dt = Filter::no_html($_POST['start_dt']);
  $end_dt = Filter::no_html($_POST['end_dt']);
  $comments = Filter::no_html($_POST['message']);
  $validate->isEmpty($name, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_YOUR_NAME);
  $validate->isEmpty($from, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_YOUR_EMAIL);
  $validate->isSingleEmail($from, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER_EMAIL);
  $validate->isEmpty($start_dt, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_START_DATE);
  $validate->isEmpty($end_dt, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_END_DATE);
  $validate->isEmpty($comments, LANG_JAVASCRIPT_PLEASE_ENTER . " " . LANG_YOUR_MESSAGE);
  $modules->call_hook('contact_owner_submit', ''); // Call any module functions
  $id = (int) @$_POST['ownerid'];
  $vehicle = (int) @$_POST['listingid'];

  if ($validate->isError())
    // whatever goes here
  {
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc many thanks for your reply, just wondering how/where I would include what you have provided into my code? Thank you Jason.

Comment: Hi Jason. No problem, a good place would be at the top of your if statement, to prevent the function running any further if $has_url is true, and use `$_POST['message']` in the `stristr()` function instead, before the `$comments` variable is defined.

Comment: Hi Marc, sorry to be a pain, but do you think you could possibly post the code how you think it should look, as I am unsure how to do it myself. Thank you once again for your valued help. Jason

Comment: Hi, Marc, you are a star that worked like a charm, just a thought, as well as including URLs could it be used to not send the message if it contained specific words, if so, how would I add that to it? Really do appreciate the help you have provided me.